# Cycling through a Radiogroup to perform actions on Radiobutton tags

Tags: android, foreach, radio-button, radio-group

So I have a RadioGroup containing 5 RadioButtons.
I want to cycling though the buttons and perform an action for each radiobutton in the group (has to do with the tag of the button.

I have no problem reading tags of individual buttons or getting the selected button in the group (using indexOfChild).
But for some reason I can't make a loop which cycles through all buttons in this radiogroup to perform an action regarding the buttons' tag.

Thanks in advance! I hope my question makes sense.

edit:
In Visual Studio I can do something comparable but with listview instead of radiogroup:

```
foreach (var item in ListView.Items.Cast<ListViewItem>())
{
stuff 
}
```

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i < radiogroup.getChildCount(); i++) { RadioButton child = (RadioButton) radioGroup.getChildAt(i); // profit}`.

Comment: How can I flag your comment as correct answer, because it works:)

Comment: I've posted an answer, you can mark it as correct by clicking the check mark near the answer. As a tip for the future, when you comment use `@username` so that user will receive a notification about your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the code below:

```
for (int i = 0; i < radiogroup.getChildCount(); i++) { 
    RadioButton child = (RadioButton) radioGroup.getChildAt(i);
    // use the button above to do what you want
}
```